# extend the functionality for my AJAX database query

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Hello Im working on the following code that is working as it is with a dropdownlist, I want the dropdownlist to be replaced with an textbox that has an autocomplete function with the data from the database.

The problem is that with an dropdownlist there are already hard coded options in the code to choose from where as with the textbox it should generate each option depending on the database values.

Im stuck on how to do this, any help would be great :)

This is my code at the moment:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
<option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','l3tm31n','records');
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"records");
$sql="SELECT * FROM workers WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>age</th>
<th>address</th>
<th>hasCar</th>
<th>speaksForeignLanguage</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['hasCar'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['speaksForeignLanguage'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You want dynamically populated dropdown list or a textbox with autocomplete like this http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL I would like it to have an textbox that autocompletes with the data from the mySQL as you type in the textbox.

Comment: Is it ok to use jquery autocomplete?

Comment: http://www.2my4edge.com/2013/08/autocomplete-search-using-php-mysql-and.html

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL That is no problem at all.

Comment: @shivanshupatel Thank you for that, I will have a look at it :)

Comment: @shivanshupatel Thank you it works, could you tell me how this can work so that the results are showing on the screen when you make the selection ? That would be a great help !

Comment: response from server will replace "content" div in index.php file  and display data from the search.php file response.

Comment: @user3541335 You can use jquery autocomplete. See my answer for more details

Answer (score 0):

Change your mysql query to

SELECT * FROM workers WHERE name LIKE '%$q%'

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with jquery [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete)

First of all, you need to include jquery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and jquery ui

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Then create your textbox;

```
<input type="text" name="names" value=""/>
```

Make your autocomplete handler,

```
<?php 
$q = $_GET["q"];

// Do your db connections

$sql = "SELECT * FROM workers WHERE name = '%" . $q . "'%";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$users = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $users[] = $row;
}

mysqli_close($con);

echo json_encode($users);


?>
```

And in your js;

```
$( "#names" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      type:"get",
      url: "getuser.php?q=" + request.term,
      success: function( data ) {
        response( $.map( data, function( user ) {
          return {
            label: user.name,
            value: user.id
          }
        }));
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 1,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    log( ui.item ?
      "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
      "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);

    $.ajax({
        "url": "getuser.php?q=" + ui.item.id,
        "type": "get",
        success: function(response) {
            $("#txtHint").html(response);
        }
    });
  },
  open: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
  },
  close: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
  }
});
```

Comment: I tryed your advise but it seems I get an error at firebug: SyntaxError: missing : after property id
 

type="get",

Comment: @user3541335 sorry my mistake. It should be `type:"get"`. See my updated answer

Comment: Ok the error is gone but nothing happens when I type something in the textbox.

Comment: Do you see ajax request on console?

Comment: No the console is empty

Comment: Yes its empty, I double checked.